# Is there an RX method which combines map and filter?

Tags: rxjs

I'm new to RxJS. I know I could just `.filter` and `.map` an observable to get the change I'm looking for. But, is there any method which combines the two into one function?

Comment: In retrospect, there's almost no reason to try and use filter and map as a single operation. If anyone else is "new to RxJS" and sees my question, don't take any of these answers. Just filter, and then map.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes there is.

FlatMap.

Suppose you have an Observable of numbers (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...) and you want to filter for even numbers and map them to x*10.

```
var tenTimesEvenNumbers = numbers.flatMap(function (x) {
  if (x % 2 === 0) {
    return Rx.Observable.just(x * 10);
  } else {
    return Rx.Observable.empty();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I never would have recognized that you could do this from the docs on flatMap. I'm selecting @paulpdaniels answer though because, it is more functional.

Comment: You mean more functional in what sense?

Comment: I mean that in this example, the filter operation must be done in the parens of the `if` statement. Say you have a common filter function that you'd like to apply to the operation many times, you could still do it, but you're left writing multiple if() statements. Additionally, you'd need to invoke it each time. 

It's much cleaner to have a solution where you can pass the filter and map functions in as separate arguments. In my mind, a solution which enables that style of coding is more 'functional'.

Comment: Arrays implement Observable too so you can just write that as `.flatMap(x => x % 2 == 0 ? [x * 10] : [])`

Comment: `flatMap` is now `mergeMap`: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/issues/333

Comment: If this question was about RxJava, that would be the right answer.

Comment: @ris8_allo_zen0 why it's not right if it's about RxJS?

Comment: @Slav it's probably OK also for RxJS, but the accepted solution is more Javascript-style.

Comment: In this example it makes no sense to use flatMap, for this just use filter and map. Interesting would have been how to map a subset and keep the other values which don't match the filter.

Answer (score 7):

As of **rxjs** v6.6.7, the solution becomes as following:

```js
    // Initialise observable with some numbers
    const numbers = of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

    // Pipe the observable using mergeMap
    const tenTimesEvenNumbers = numbers.pipe(
      mergeMap((x: number) => {
        // If the number is even, return an observable containing the number multiplied by ten
        // Otherwise return an empty observable
        return x % 2 === 0 ? of(x * 10) : EMPTY;
      })
    );

    // Subscribe to the observable and print the values
    tenTimesEvenNumbers.subscribe((value: number) =>
      console.log('Value:', value)
    );
```

The above will print:

> ```
> Value: 20
> Value: 40
> Value: 60
> Value: 80
> Value: 100
> ```

Here is a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-baydyt?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a higher order function.

For example, here is a non-RxJS function to do the heavy lifting of producing the desired list. It takes two functions, the filter and map functions and returns a function that takes the list you are interested in processing.

```
function filterMap<A, B>(filterFn: (a: A) => boolean, mapFn: (a: A) => B): (as: A[]) => B[] {
   return (as) => as.reduce((acc, a) => {
     if (filterFn(a)) acc.push(mapFn(a));
     return acc;
   }, []);
}
```

You can ignore the types if using plain javascript.

filterMap can then be used like this:

```
const isEven = (a) => a % 2 === 0;
const doubleValue = (a) => a = 2 * a;
const doubleEvens = filterMap(isEven, doubleValue);
const myResult = doubleEvens([1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Now you can use filterMap either directly in a rxjs map or define a new pipe function. Here is an example use:

```
of([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).pipe(
  map(doubleEvens)
).subscribe(console.log);
```

There a couple of advantages

- You can reuse filterMap to define any combination of filter and map you need
- The operations can be given meaningful names
- The list is iterated once
- No extra observables are created

Comment: @judos had a comment about only mapping over only a subset and also keep the values that don't match. Solutions: 1) Just use map 2) define `filterApplyMap` similar to `filterMap` but add else clause and do `acc.push(a)` the final return type will be (A|B)[], same as #1, which is not that pretty 3) define `filterPartitionMap` which takes a pair of lists as the accumulator and pushes the appropriate value onto the appropriate list. Return type will be [A[], B[]]. I put B[] on right to be consistent with "true" value is on right.