# Multiple chain of map fillter in rxjava2 vs single for loop on Large Collection

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have a question on performance of rxjava2 and single for loop over a really large collection. example

lets say i have a collection with 10000 elements and i want to map and filter on it in rxjava2 then does map iterates on all the items first? and then again filter iterates on all the items? if so then single for loop over the collection is better is it not?

Comment: By the way 10000 elements is just an example since i wanted the collection to be as large as possible. just someone please clarify why using chain of map reduce filter map is good thing?

Comment: A single loop with mapping and filtering will iterate 10000 elements. Map then filter will do 20000 loops.

Comment: is it not that map and filter are reactive stream which makes them iterate once to all element and then perform both map and filter

Comment: No, map will just return an observable of the list and then filter will use it. Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446977/is-there-an-rx-method-which-combines-map-and-filter. This uses flatMap to create a custom map+filter.

Answer (score 0):

10000 elements is a lot of elements for an android app.

But yes, doing it in a single loop will be faster rather than calling map and filter.

It will be better if you do a performance test of it yourself.